# Check if string only contains numbers in php

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to detect if a string I have contain only number, not containing a `letter`, `comma`, or `dot`. 
For example like this:

```
083322 -> valid
55403.22 -> invalid
1212133 -> valid
61,23311 -> invalid
890022 -> valid
09e22 -> invalid
```

I already used `is_numeric` and `ctype_digit` but it's not valid

Comment: Try this `^\d+$`

Comment: `ctype_digit` does exactly what you want https://3v4l.org/YcOSo

Comment: Are you sure the input was a string? `ctype_digit` only works with strings, not numbers.

Comment: I know this is several years old now, but the suggested duplicate is for Javascript, whereas this question is about PHP so is not particularly helpful.

Comment: I have added a PHP dupe target as well @Steven  When this question was posted in 2018, there will be at least 10 other pages already dedicated to this task.  This is what I call a super-duplicate.  If contributors were more discerning, this page would have been closed without any answers at all.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You want to use preg_match in that case as both 61,23311 and 55403.22 are valid numbers (depending on locale).
i.e.

```
if (preg_match("/^\d+$/", $number)) {
    return "is valid"
} else {
    return "invalid"
}
```

Comment: This could match digits in other locales that aren't 0-9 which isn't what you want. Replace \d with [0-9] or use ctype_digit() https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php

Answer (score 11):

what about

```
if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $str)) {
  echo "valid";
} else {
  echo "invalid";
}
```